# JavaFX 2: self-disable on mouseEntered, strange behavior

Tags: javafx-2, mouseevent

If a node tries to disable itself on mouse entered,
say

```
final Button btn = new Button("Hello");

btn.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        btn.setDisable(true);
        System.out.println("Mouse in");
    }
});

btn.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        btn.setDisable(false);
        System.out.println("Mouse out");
    }
});
```

I've expected single "Mouse in" while the cursor is
over the button, but the button is "blinking" and
"Mouse in", "Mouse out" are written over and over again.

Is this some kind of a bug, because similar code
in Swing behaves as I expect?

Comment: Actually, I get what I want with this:
btn.setMouseTransparent(true);

Comment: Then how it will handle mouse events again? The button will stay disabled for further mouse events.

Comment: In my original program, I have some checkboxes
which I want to select/deselect only programatically,
and they have some text fill colors set, because of
what I don't want to disable them permanently.
So, just setMouseTransparent(true) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when a button gets disabled, the mouse is leaving it, thus firing a MouseExitedEvent.

To avoid this, use setMouseTransparent to make the control unaware of mouseevents before calling setDisable.

Comment: Thank you! In the meanwhile, I've got it :)